# How to find a particular URL in an HTML file with python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, url

There is a URL with a .bin attachment in my HTML file.
My goal is to extract the full link with my Python script.  I am running this script across many HTML files and the location of the .bin URL may change.
If I was able to get the index of the beginning of the URL and the end, I could extract it that way.

I tried doing a word search through the HTML files but there are a few .bin URLS, I only want the first one.  Any ideas would be appreciated. Or any other methods.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
html_link = "www.mywebsitelink.com"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(html_link)
webContent = response.read()
```

Comment: I don' t quite understand? Do you want to parse the HTML file and extract first occurrence of link with .bin file? If yes, you can use `beautifulsoup` library to parse the HTML document.

Comment: It depends. Sometimes URLs may be disguised somewhat in Javascript code, sometimes one may want only those that appear in proper `<a` HTML links. It might be a good idea if you could show us a sample HTML file that you want to process, indicating which URL you want to extract. If the HTML is of any size at all you could post it on pastebin.com for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at using [Regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

In your example, you will probably be looking for something like:

```
^http://.+\.bin$
```

You can test this out and explore what each part of the Regex expression means using this helpful tool: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GBzkKC/1)

Your code would probably look something like this:

```
import re

bin_url = re.search("^http://.+\.bin$", webContent)
```

Comment: Took me some time to figure out regex.  But it worked!